# Rellenar radio buttom y check mediante un for con datos del servidor Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery

tengo una pequeña duda sobre como rellenarlos obteniendo los datos del servidor.

Tengo un index.html:

```
    <form name="frmListadoPiezas3" id="frmListadoPiezas3" class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Listado de piezas de un producto Radio</legend>

    <!-- Select Basic -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lstProductosListado3">Producto</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="Radio" id="lstProductosListado3" name="lstProductosListado3" class="form-control">


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="btnListar"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="button" id="btnListar3" name="btnListar3" class="btn btn-success" value="Listar"></input>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Y un index.js:

```
    function procesarRellenarProductos(listadoProductos)
{
    console.log(listadoProductos);
    $("#lstProductosListado3").empty();
    let sOption="";
    for(let i=0;i<listadoProductos.length;i++)
    {
        sOption += "<option value='"+listadoProductos[i].idproducto+"'>"+listadoProductos[i].nombre+"</option>"
    }

    $("#lstProductosListado").html(sOption);

}
```

La función procesarRellenarProductos tal como esta ahora mismo me rellena un desplegable que funciona correctamente, pero cuando quiero que me rellene un radio y un check (utilizando una función para cada uno) no se como debo de hacerlo dentro del for. He probado varias cosas y no me muestra nada, solo 1 circulo de radio vacío. El llenado lo hago mediante ajax llamando a un fichero php donde tengo la conexión y consulta al servidor.

Esta es la parte que no se ponerla:

```
sOption += "<option value='"+listadoProductos[i].idproducto+"'>"+listadoProductos[i].nombre+"</option>"
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Añado las funciones que llaman al servidor:

```
    function rellenarCombosProductos()
{
    var iListaProductos = null;
    if(localStorage["nombreProductos"] != null)
    {
        iListaProductos = JSON.parse(localStorage["nombreProductos"]);
        procesarRellenarComboProductos(iListaProductos);
    }
    else
    {
        let oAjax = instanciarXHR();

        var sURL = "./php/getProductos.php";

        oAjax.open("GET", encodeURI(sURL));

        oAjax.addEventListener("readystatechange", procesarRespuesta);

        oAjax.send();
    }
}

function procesarRespuesta()
{ 
    var oAjax = this;
    //console.log(oAjax.responseText)

    if (oAjax.readyState == 4 && oAjax.status == 200) 
    {
       let listadoProductos =  JSON.parse(oAjax.responseText);
       console.log(listadoProductos)
        procesarRellenarComboProductos(listadoProductos);
        localStorage["nombreProductos"] = JSON.stringify(listadoProductos);

    }
}

    function instanciarXHR() {
    var xhttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else // code for IE5 and IE6
    {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xhttp;
}
```

Comment: En qué parte del html estás introduciendo esas opciones? Es decir, ¿cómo lo estas agregando al html?

Comment: La idea es cargar mediante la función: procesarRellenarProductos (que esta en index.js) los radio button que previamente han sido cargados mediante ayax desde un fichero .php. En el html no se inserta nada, todo se hace en el .js @JeanGotopo

Comment: Lo que quise preguntar es cómo lo insertas en el DOM. No estás usando el método innerHtml para mostrarlos o renderizarlos en la página?

Comment: con el método html() de jquery @JeanGotopo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin probar nada de tu código veo varías cosas que no son correctas del todo como puede ser el añadir a un elemento option a un input, el elemento option tiene que ser explicitamente el hijo del elemento select.

Aparte de esto veo otra cosa más, estas intentando crear supuestamente un radio button, pues para ello si que tendrías que usar inputs, tienes que usar la propiedad type con el valor radio, osea type="radio"

Aqui un ejemplo: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

El error lo tienes en esta línea:

```
$("#lstProductosListado").html(sOption);
```

Porque ?
Pues porque no llego a ver ningún elemento del html que has pasado con esta id, el más cercano y supongo que te refieres a este: **#lstProductosListado3**

Aparte de todo esto lo que te he comentado, comentar que para que los radios sean excluyentes, les tienes que poner el mismo nombre.

Osea que en la "sOption +=" que tienes en el bucle for, pon lo siguiente:

```
sOption += "<input type='radio' name='producto' value='"+listadoProductos[i].nombre+"'>";
```

También comentar que no es una buena practica hacer uso de la función html() ya que si por ejemplo ya tienes elementos hijos en el elemento donde hagas uso de esta función, los eliminara, recomiendo hacer uso de la función **append** o **appendTo**.

Usas el listado de productos como un array lo cual es un poco raro, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
//Primero conseguiría vía el selector, el elemento donde quisiera poner la lista de radios.

let listaAqui = $(".form-group div.col-md-4").first();

//Ahora usaría lo que es el JSON.parse para iterar sobre cada clave y valor, obviamente nos interesa el valor, destacar que no se como es la estructura de tu JSON así que me la inventare

/*Así es como creo que es tu estructura 
{"1" : {"idproducto" : 1, "nombre" : "NombreProducto"},...}
*/

//Una vez sabido esto vamos al lio, ejemplo completo:

$(function(){

    let listaAqui = $(".form-group div.col-md-4").first();

    JSON.parse('{"1" : {"idproducto" : 1, "nombre" : "Lena"}, "2" : {"idproducto" : 2, "nombre" : "Lena2"}}', function(k, v){
        
        if(this instanceof Object && k === "idproducto"){
            
            
            $(listaAqui).append($("<div></div>").append($("<input/>").attr({type : "radio", name : "producto", id : this.idproducto, value : this.idproducto}))
                                                .append($("<label></label>").attr("for", this.idproducto).text(this.nombre)));
            
        }

    });

});
```

En el caso del checkbox es parecido, aquí te paso la sintaxis:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Sería lo mismo de antes, concaténalo como lo veas, refiriéndome al ejemplo que usas con el método html()

Por ultimo comentar que supongo que has probado que la devolución de datos es correcta vía el depurador, de todos modos, te recomiendo hacer uso de la función $.ajax(), si quieres usar mi ejemplo sobre el añadido de datos, adáptalo a tu proyecto.

Te voy a dejar el HTML y el JS para que veas mejor como adaptarlo, también recordar que use el jquery en local, tendrías que cambiar el src del elemento script.

HTML: https://pastebin.com/MrAeawm8

JS: https://pastebin.com/8b1XymzK

Este ultimo es el de la buena práctica.

Comment: Pero mandando con .html() a lstProductosListado3 me funciona perfecto en el caso del desplegable. Voy a tratar de implementar tu respuesta a ver si puedo hacer que funcione.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que al añadir el elemento option en un input no es correcto, si lo que quieres son los radio button pues ve añadiendo los inputs, como poco usa el selector $(".form-group div.col-md-4").first() para saber donde añadir los nuevos inputs y luego si quieres, añades con el html tal como te he comentado en la respuesta, aunque recuerda que es mala practica pero más simple también.

Comment: No, no consigo que me funcione. Añadiendo esto al for: sOption += "<input type='radio' name='producto' value='"+listadoProductos[i].nombre+"'>"; debería funcionar?

Comment: Si no te lo añade puede ser debido a $("#lstProductosListado").html(sOption); Si al id que has usado, prueba con lo que te he comentado -> $(".form-group div.col-md-4").first().html(sOption);

Comment: No, no funciona. Me aparece un radio buttom gigante en blanco y tampoco me arroja ningún error.

Comment: Puedes poner el html de salida ? para tener más ideas de lo que ocurre, también el js del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar estás introduciendo con el método hmtl() donde no es:

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="lstProductosListado3">Producto</label>
      <div class="col-md-4" id="opciones">
        <input type="Radio" id="lstProductosListado3" name="lstProductosListado3" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Luego con el método html():

```
$("#opciones").html(sOption);
```

Comment: Tal como esta, funciona perfectamente porque lo esta insertando en el id="lstProductosListado3", de hecho haciendo un desplegable funciona y me aparecen los datos.